# How to use Marionette 3 Regions with existing page content? (e.g. server generated HTML)

Tags: backbone.js, frontend, marionette

I'm trying to apply Marionette into our architecture as it seems to fit our current application better than other solutions. Our frontend HTML is mostly server-side generated using PHP and Twig (just to give some context).

I'm now trying to use Marionette 3 Regions to achieve View compositions in a context where header, footer and generally the main content HTML are already there in the page.

I couldn't find any example with this approach so I'm asking here if someone could give some advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily attach views to existing DOM elements using marionette:

```
        var MyView = Mn.View({
      el: '#base-element',
  template: false
    });
```

Also reference: http://marionettejs.com/docs/master/marionette.view.html

Comment: That was my approach for a single view. However I wasn't able to find a more extended example using Regions. Then I found this issue on Github Marionette project https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/3128 The trick with Regions is to not render the child Views but only initialize/show them.